# Is a C++11 assignment expression evaluated right to left?

Tags: c++, c++11, expression, expression-evaluation

The order of evaluation of an expression has always been a source of unspecified behaviors in C++. Has the C++11 standard finally stated what the order of evaluation should be?

Do we now know the values of `var1` and `var2` of the following expression:

```
int var1 =10, var2=20;
var1 = var2 = 30;
```

Will it be `var1=30 and var2=30`, or `var1=20 and var2=30`?

Comment: @Dariusz: The code also has nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: @KerrekSB this is MY question and I know what I wanted to ask. While I may have problems with expressing what I mean, the code stands. Your answer has nothing to do with what I intended to post.

Comment: @Dariusz: Nonsense. You're asking about oder of evaluation of expressions, and the code you posted has nothing to do with that. The expression you posted is `a = b`, where `b` is `var2 = 30` and has value `30`, and `a` is `var1` and is an lvalue. Ordering has nothing to do with the result of the evaluation of this expression.

Comment: @Dariusz: To give a different perspective: It seems that you're confusing matters of grammar (operator associativity, which determines *how source code is parsed*), and the abstract rules of how expressions are evaluated. There's nothing ambiguous here.

Comment: The question was invalid in the first place. I haven't managed to properly phrase what I wanted to ask, I'd like to create the question from scratch and properly this time and get real answers to a question not edited 10 times. Please delete this one.

Comment: @KerrekSB I have finally managed to ask what I wanted to ask, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585808/order-of-evaluation-of-assingment-subexpressions-in-c11

Comment: @Dariusz: Thanks. I also added  a bit of text addressing your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var1 = var2 = 30;
```

Both shall be `30` and it's specified by standard. The thing which is not specified is, if assigning operands are complex expression which must be evaluated before assigment, what's the sequence of evaluating them?

```
(expr1) = (expr2) = x;
   1         2

or

(expr1) = (expr2) = x;
   2         1
```

Comment: Has it always been? What is the order of evaluating these complex expressions now and what has it been?

Comment: We don't know the order and it's unspecified by standard.

Answer (score 7):

No, the new standard does not specify a sequencing *or* ordering of evaluations of all subexpressions.

The expression `a + b + c` is grouped grammatically as `(a + b) + c`, but the three subexpressions `a`, `b` and `c` can be evaluated in any order and the evaluations are not sequenced with respect to each other.

To make this more concrete, consider:

```
int main()
{
    return printf("Hello") + printf("World") + printf("\n");
}
```

---

As for your code: There is no ambiguity there. It is one expression, an assignment expression of the form `a = b`, where `a` is the lvalue `var1` and `b` is the subexpression `var2 = 30`. The fact that you're wondering whether `var1` ends up as `20` or as `30` leads me to believe that you're unsure about the operator associativity (for `=`). That, however, has never been ambiguous and is perfectly well specified in all language variants I can think of. The assigment operator associates on the right, leading to the subexpressions `a` and `b` that I have described. This (extremely fundamental) aspect of the language has not been changed in C++11.

If you really want to combine the two problems, you should consider the following expression:

```
var1 = 10;
(var1 = 20) = (var2 = var1);
```

Now the final expression is also `a = b`, but both `a` and `b` are non-trivial subexpression whose evaluation is *not* ordered.

Comment: The question is about `=` (which is right-to-left), not `+` (which is left-to-right). See [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: @jrok The OP seemed to be confused about something, so an answer should try to address that and help, not add to the confusion. I didn't downvote this answer as it, as you said, addresses the same basic point, but it's still not a good answer - yours is better which is why I upvoted yours.

Comment: @DanielFrey: it's *associativity*, not *precedence*. I've added a paragraph addressing the OP's code.

Comment: +1 Now there is something helpful and yes, you are correct that it's associativity and not the precedence.

Answer (score 3):

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left.

This doesn't tell us anything about evaluation order. It merely means that `a = b = c` is parsed as `a = (b = c)` and not `(a = b) = c`.

`1.9/15` still applies:

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.

Sequencing rules introduce partial ordering only. In an expression like this:

```
(x+42) = (y+42)
```

it is guaranteed that both subexpressions `(x+42)` and `(y+42)` are executed before the assignment to the result of (x+42) occurs, but the two subexpressions themselves are not sequenced. Either can be executed before the other one and they can even be interleaved and the order need not be consistent during the execution of the program.