# Order of evaluation of assignment subexpressions

Tags: c++, c++11, variable-assignment, operator-precedence

[The C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (5.17, expr.ass) states that

> In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation
>   of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of
>   the assignment expression. With respect to an
>   indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of a compound
>   assignment is a single evaluation

Does this mean, that the expression:

```
int a = 1, b = 10;
int c = (a+=1) + (b+=1);

if ( c == 10+1+1+1 ) {
    printf("this is guaranteed");
} else {
    printf("not guaranteed"); 
}
```

will always evaluate to `c==23`?

Comment: I don't think this has *ever* been confusing or ambiguous. The new rules in C++11 specify details of "sequenced-before"/"happens-before" relationships needed for the new, more specific memory model of the language, but they don't change anything with regards to single-threaded execution of the typical "problem code" snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has always been guaranteed, and the sequenced before rules
(or the sequence point rules in pre-C++11) aren't need to
determine this.  In C++, each (sub-)expression has two important
effects in the generated code: it has a value (unless it is of
type `void`), and it may have side effects.  The sequenced
before/sequence point rules affect when the side effects are
guaranteed to have taken place; they have no effect on the value
of the sub-expressions.  In your case, for example, the *value*
of `(a += 1)` is the value `a` will have after the assignment,
regardless of when the actual assignment takes place.

In C++11, the actual modification of `a` is guaranteed to take
place before the modification of `c`; in pre C++11, there was no
guarantee concerning the order.  In this case, however, there is
no way a conforming program could see this difference, so it
doesn't matter.  (It would matter in cases like `c = (c += 1)`,
which would be undefined behavior in pre-C++11.)

Comment: Your second paragraph is an answer to I actually wanted to ask - and even did while ago, once I came up with a proper example.

Comment: `c = (c += 1)` **is** still UB, no? Evaluations of `c` and `(c+=1)` are unsequenced.

Comment: @jrok I'm not sure.  There are clearly a couple more "sequenced before" than there were sequence points before, which should make some things defined which weren't previously.  I think this is one of them, but I wouldn't swear to it.

Comment: @jrok: I would have thought that the UB is because `c` is modified more than once without sequencing. The value computation is sequenced, but are the side effects (namely of `c += 1`) sequenced, too?

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
int c = (a+=1) + (b+=1);
```

(edit: added the missing brackets, I think this is what you intended)

has the following subexpressions

```
(1) a+=1
(2) b+=1
(3) (1)+(2)
(4) c = (3)
```

The order in which (1) and (2) are evaluated is unspecified, the compiler is free to choose any order it likes.

Both (1) and (2) must be evaluated *before* the compiler can evaluate (3).

(3) must be evaluated *before* the compiler can evaluate (4).

Now as the order of evaluation of (1) and (2) does not matter, the overall result is well defined, your code will always yield `13` and print "this is now standard". Note that is has always been this way, this is not new with C++11.

Comment: You are right, of course. My question is obvious. I seem to have an idea in the back of my head that this part of the standard is more strict than ever before, but I can't create a good example of it.

Comment: Your answer is irrelevant because the compiler shall issue an error for his expression int c = a += 1 + b += 1;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Therefore the "(edit: ...)". *Edit:* As confimed by the edit of the OPs question now.

Answer (score 1):

In your example the compiler shall issue an error because the priority of the addition operator is higher than priority of the assignment operator. So at first 1 + b will be calculated and then there will be an attempt to assign 1 to expression ( 1 + b ) but ( 1 + b ) is not an lvalue.

Comment: Yes, `a+=1` is an lvalue, I tested it, and also I now know what you mean, the code was fixed some time ago

Comment: Dariusz your comment is irrelevant because I said about expression 1 + b as it was written originally in the post. The author of the post then updated it inserting parentheses.

Comment: It was me. And yes I did. I didn't understand your answer at first. A comment would've been anough, it was a typo.